# Trouble with Middleman installation in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv, middleman

I installed middleman using `gem install middleman`, and I can see the gem listed in my local gem list

`middleman (4.3.5)
middleman-cli (4.3.5)
middleman-core(4.3.5`

but when I enter `middleman -v` I get
`Unknown switches "-v"`

If I enter `middleman --version` I get
`Unknown switches "--version"
Did you mean? "--verbose"`

`which middleman` returns `home/.rbenv/shims/middleman`
`which ruby` returns `home/.rbenv/shims/ruby`
I'm running ruby version 2.6.3 by default
on Ubuntu 18.04

I've been trying to install Middleman for two days and keep running into problems; it's turning into a nightmare!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the problem, exactly? `middleman` is successfully installed. It just doesn't support the switches you're trying to pass. Did you try `middleman init project_name` as defined in the [README](https://github.com/middleman/middleman#getting-started)? Because the fact that you're getting the error messages you've shown indicates that middleman IS installed correctly and WILL work correctly. You just have to run it, like so:

```
foo:~|⇒  which middleman
/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/middleman
foo:~|⇒  middleman
/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:111: warning: BigDecimal.new is deprecated; use BigDecimal() method instead.
== Could not find a Middleman project config.rb
foo:~|⇒  middleman --version
/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:111: warning: BigDecimal.new is deprecated; use BigDecimal() method instead.
Unknown switches "--version"
Did you mean?  "--verbose"
foo:~|⇒  middleman init foo
/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:111: warning: BigDecimal.new is deprecated; use BigDecimal() method instead.
         run  git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/middleman/middleman-templates-default.git /var/folders/ts/qq2cd6pn42d15jrhc36cxbtw0000gn/T/d20191106-69912-29f30z from "."
Cloning into '/var/folders/ts/qq2cd6pn42d15jrhc36cxbtw0000gn/T/d20191106-69912-29f30z'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 19, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (19/19), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
remote: Total 19 (delta 0), reused 12 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (19/19), done.
       exist
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  config.rb
      create  source/images/.keep
      create  source/index.html.erb
      create  source/javascripts/site.js
      create  source/layouts/layout.erb
      create  source/stylesheets/site.css.scss
         run  bundle install from "./foo"
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mswin32, x86-mingw32, java, x64-mingw32. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mswin32 x86-mingw32 java x64-mingw32`.
The dependency wdm (~> 0.1) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mswin32, x86-mingw32, x64-mingw32. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mswin32 x86-mingw32 x64-mingw32`.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...............
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
Using i18n 0.9.5
Fetching minitest 5.13.0
Installing minitest 5.13.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.5
Fetching activesupport 5.0.7.2
Installing activesupport 5.0.7.2
Fetching public_suffix 4.0.1
Installing public_suffix 4.0.1
Fetching addressable 2.7.0
Installing addressable 2.7.0
Using execjs 2.7.0
Fetching autoprefixer-rails 9.7.1
Installing autoprefixer-rails 9.7.1
Using backports 3.15.0
Using bundler 1.17.3
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using contracts 0.13.0
Using dotenv 2.7.5
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using fast_blank 1.0.0
Using fastimage 2.1.7
Using ffi 1.11.1
Using temple 0.8.2
Fetching tilt 2.0.10
Installing tilt 2.0.10
Using haml 5.1.2
Using hamster 3.0.0
Using hashie 3.6.0
Using kramdown 1.17.0
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Using rb-inotify 0.10.0
Using listen 3.0.8
Using memoist 0.16.0
Using thor 0.20.3
Using middleman-cli 4.3.5
Using padrino-support 0.13.3.4
Using padrino-helpers 0.13.3.4
Fetching parallel 1.18.0
Installing parallel 1.18.0
Using rack 2.0.7
Using sassc 2.2.1
Using servolux 0.13.0
Using uglifier 3.2.0
Using middleman-core 4.3.5
Using middleman 4.3.5
Fetching middleman-autoprefixer 2.10.1
Installing middleman-autoprefixer 2.10.1
Bundle complete! 4 Gemfile dependencies, 42 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
foo:~|⇒
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, it WAS correctly installed! To check for the version I needed to enter the command without hyphens (`middleman version`).  Thank you!